# Allowing user to enter French,Spanish and Korean language in content of Umbraco input Control

Tags: umbraco

We are using Umbraco web application in English language. We need to add
French,Spanish and Korean language in our application where we should be allow user to type and add content in French,Spanish and Korean language.

Question : How we can allow user to input content in French,Spanish and Korean language . Note* : Default language of system is English.

Please help me to get out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Umbraco doesn't have built in language variants - so the classic way to do it is to create language specific "sites" as described here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/tutorials/multilanguage-setup/

Answer (score 1):

A different solution could be to use the Vorto package. Vorto wraps itself around your existing datatypes, allowing you to put in an extra "layer" so every property can have different values/settings for each language in your site.

There's a link to it here - with instructions on how to get started using it:
https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/vorto/